# Facebook Opengraph Console error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, action, facebook-opengraph

Hello people i am trying new action to post picture on facebook and during posting i am facing a error which i cant able to make it work properly

The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least one of the following properties must be specified:

Comment: do you have any object attached with your action? and please do share your code you are using to publish the action.

Comment: hello smita thanks for replying :)

here is code
http://pastebin.com/JsCv63Bn

Comment: ok, how are you posting the action? can you share the code which post action to facebook?

Comment: here is code pastebin.com/JsCv63Bn
or visit url = www.lolzspot.org 
you ll then better understand ... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for posting your action, with Javascript SDK for posting image you should try something like:

```
FB.api('/me/bhlolzspot:laugh_out_loud', 'post', 
  { funniest_picture : 'OBJECT_URL',image[0][url]=http://www.yourdomain.com/images/image.jpg,image[0][user_generated]=true });
```

I am assuming `laugh_out_loud` is your action name and `funniest_picture` is your object name. 
at `OBJECT_URL`, all your meta tags should be in place and i can see there is a missing og:image tag, there you should put the image you want to post with action on facebook.

hope it helps.

Comment: thnx kumari :P ... ^^ kaam chal gaya :P